# Specify CSS percentage width as a function of viewport width

Tags: html, css, viewport-units, css-calc

I have some paragraphs of text on my webpage that I would like to format to occupy a certain percentage of the page's width. I've decided that when the page is 800px wide, the text should occupy 80% of the page's width, and when the page is 1440px wide, the text should occupy 40% of the page's width. The issue, however, is that I want there to be a smooth transition between different widths meaning that at 1120px wide, the text will occupy 60% of the page's width. Essentially, I want to define an expression that takes the current width as a pixel value, operates on the numerical value, and then convert the numerical output to a certain percentage. Is there a way to implement this in CSS only? I know it's possible with Javascript, but I'd like to utilize more pure CSS in my design.

EDIT: If I was to implement this into JavaScript, I would use something similar to the following:

```
window.onresize = () => {
    let currentWidth = window.innerWidth
    let newTextboxWidth = 130 - (currentWidth / 16)
    textbox.style.width = Math.max(40, Math.min(newTextboxWidth, 80)) + “%”
}
```

This allows for a smooth continuum of values that fits the given specifications, as opposed to a solution that jumps around between percentage values.

Comment: What would be your formula, given you had access to Javascript?

Comment: The behavior described seems unusual.  If I understand, the resultant widths would be 800px * 80% = 640px, 1120px * 60% = 672px, 1440px * 40% = 576px.  That is, the width of the text would get wider then narrower as the page width increases from 800px to 1440px.

Comment: @Loe very good point, I hadn’t considered that my linear percentage function would become a quadratic when multiplied by the page width, meaning that there is a maximum width at 1040px wide. The formula will need to be adjusted accordingly in order to have a linear pixel output.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is available via `vw` (viewport width) and [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries).

```css
p { 
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  width: 80vw; 
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1120px) {
  p { width: 60vw; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
  p { width: 40vw; }
}
```